# Avoid larger (bloated) size when saving (regression) model in R (environments)

Tags: r

I want to create a regression model within another function; but my problem is that when saving the model it becomes really, really big because other data in the environment is being saved with it. Thus, I think the solution might be to handle different environments; [this](https://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Model-object-when-generated-in-a-function-saves-entire-environment-when-saved-td4723192.html) helped me understand this better. Below I have explained the problems in a few steps.

```
# Helper function just to quickly assess how big the object becomes when being saved.
saveSize <- function (object) {
  tf <- tempfile(fileext = ".RData")
  on.exit(unlink(tf))
  save(object, file = tf)
  file.size(tf)
}

# Subset of columns to be used
subset = 1:4

# Model size to compare with; i.e., not created within a function
model1 <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, data = iris, subset = subset)
saveSize(model1)
# Size = 965

# Function where there are other data that should NOT be saved. 
Function2 <- function (subset){
  data_not_to_be_saved <- 1:1e+15
  model2 <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, data = iris, subset = subset)
}
model2 <- Function2(subset)
saveSize(model2) 
# Size = 1148 ; Problematic that size is larger that model 1.

# Solution to above is to create a new environment
Function3 <- function (subset){
  data_not_to_be_saved <- 1:1e+15
  # New environment
  env <- new.env(parent = globalenv())
  env$subset <- subset
  with(env, lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, data = iris, subset = subset))
}
model3 <- Function3(subset)
saveSize(model3) 
# 1002 # Success: considerably smaller than in Function 2. 



# PROBLEM: Getting solution in Function 3 to work within another function. 

# This function runs but result in large sized object again
# Also note that I do not want to call iris dataset within the lm call. 
Function5 <- function (subset){
  
  data_not_to_be_saved <- 1:1e+15
  
  Function5 <- function (subset) {
    
    env <- new.env(parent = globalenv())
    env$subset <- subset
    env$datainenvorment <- iris
    
    with(env, lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, data = datainenvorment, subset = subset))
  }
  model5 <- Function5(subset)
}

model5 <- Function5(subset)
saveSize(model5)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution you are using works correctly. You do not see it as in new R versions sequential integer vectors are very memory efficient. This small differences comes from a small overhead of additional variables like `env` variable. Where most important is that `data_not_to_be_saved` variable is skipped.

Use some bigger data to see it more clearly.

```r
data_not_to_be_saved <- rnorm(10**5)
```

What is the source of this problem. The `lm` returns an object which contains reference to other environments (e.g. function environments provide an access to all variables from the place where it was defined). Additionally `save` function with default parameters looking for needed variables across all possible envs.

```r
str(model5)
# like   .. .. ..- attr(*, ".Environment")=<environment: 0x7fdc9e6c2b68>
```

Another solution might be to use `lm.fit` function which returning only base structures. Here no additional reference will be taken

```r
model_fit <- lm.fit(cbind(1,iris$Sepal.Width[subset]), iris$Sepal.Length[subset])
```